# passing an xml in nusoap

Tags: php, xml, version, nusoap

Good day,

I am having trouble passing an xml in nusoap.

sample: 
I pass this xml

```
<test>123</test>
```

The nusoap response is

```
test123/test
```

The greater than and less than sign is removed.

*This is my code for the server:*

---

```
require_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');
$server = new nusoap_server; // Create server instance

$server->configureWSDL('demows','http://example.org/demo');

$server->register('myFunction',
    array("param"=>"xsd:string"), // input
    array("result"=>"xsd:string"), // output
    'http://example.org/demo'
);

function myFunction($parameters) {
    return $parameters;
}

// Use the request to try to invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

---

*This is my code for the client:*

---

```
require_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/nusoap/ws.php?wsdl', true);

$clientparam = '<test>123</test>';

$result = $client->call('myFunction', 
    array('param'=>$clientparam)
);

print_r($result);
```

---

*Note that the above code is working on PHP Version 5.3.0 but NOT on PHP Version 5.2.0-8+etch13 which is the one on our production is using.

I've searched the net for any issues on the 2 version but none found.
Any help is highly appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade you libxml2 and rebuild PHP.

Comment: I confirm this is the bug, as reported by Woody. Just downgrade libxml2 (or upgrade it's even better). You don't have to rebuild PHP though, if you're using standard packages, just don't forget to restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know nusoap at all, but it sounds like your entities are being discarded.
It might be worth controlling the entities at either end, for instance by changing '>' for &gt;, '<' for &lt; either manually or using a function such as htmlentities()

Comment: already tried that but all ampersands are being remove.
&gt; becomes gt;
&lt; becomes lt;

thus I still don't have the correct xml format

Comment: Definitely seems like it is removing entities then. Do you have any control on the other side, ie, could you not use some non entity characters (maybe like [test]123[/test]) and reconstruct on the other side?.
There are a few reports of similar with libxml stripping entities, such as this: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45996 which was fixed in 5.2.9

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using a different version of nusoap than me, but I've been using the proxy, which seems to be working. I also instantiate the client with soapclient rather than nusoap_client (hadn't seen that before):

```
 $client = new soapclient('http://localhost/nusoap/ws.php?wsdl', true);
 $proxy = $client->getProxy();
 $response = $proxy->call("myfunction", array('test' => 123));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and the answer is in **soapval** class.

Little messy but simple example is [here](http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapprog2.htm).
In quick - you have to wrap with this class any non-generic type, that means i.e. php array. Nesting of this wraps could of course happen but it's not against design.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass xml value within a soap message and you control both the server and the client (or at least you can instruct the client), why not base64 encode your xml. Then the parser will just see it as a normal string and not get confused.